# Composite @NaturalId in Hibernate entity

Tags: java, database, hibernate, triggers, naturalid

For generation id's of entities application uses trigger. So, for assigning generated values to entities we use constructions like this:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "INVOICE_ID")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "trigger")
@GenericGenerator(name = "trigger", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.SelectGenerator")
private Long invoiceId;

@Column(name = "INVOICE_AMOUNT")
@NaturalId(mutable = true)
private Double invoiceAmount;
```

`SelectorGenerator` requires to use `@NaturalId` for some field, which should has(logically) unique value. But some tables don't have anyone field which has all unique values. `SelectGenerator` doesn't support multiple natural id's. How can we get round this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As available solution for cases like this we changed a little mechanism of getting IDs of entities. Instead of using

`@GenericGenerator(name = "trigger", strategy ="org.hibernate.id.SelectGenerator")`

we prefered to use database sequence generator

```
@Id
@Column(name = "INVOICE_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "invoice_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "invoice_id_seq", sequenceName = "INVOICE_ID_SEQ")
private Long invoiceId;
```

It doesn't requre `@NaturalId` and it solved our problem.